# External library treating polygons and calculating their fractal dimension

Tags: c++, geometry, 2d

I'm looking at a physical problem on an hexagonal 2d lattice. It's now a geometrical problem, only a subset of the edges of the lattice are of interest, I'm given this set. I should then restrict myself to the closed curves that I can compose with these edges. From these polygons I'd like to extract information such as their diameters (maximal distance between two of its points)) and their fractal dimension.

I still don't see how to it from the raw initial data (unordered array of edges) and so I'd like to know if there are packages/library that could help me. From drawing each one of these edges they could return the closed loops they form and after that, analyzing each of these polygons individually.

Thank you.

Comment: I did, and from the results I stated reading the documentation of several of them Cgal, wykobi, boost and geometric tools libraries but none of seem to be fitted for that. Especially the calculus of the fractal dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the box-counting algorithm to compute the fractal dimension:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension.

Comment: I'm thinking about adding to my program but it could be cumbersome because of the way I started to code it. And as it is not an important of my program, more of a sanity check on my simulation, I was looking for a program doing it. Apparently, it is implemented by default in MATLAB so I was expecting it to be part of some popular geometric C++ library.

Comment: Here's a box covering library:http://www-levich.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~hmakse/modules.py